# Open menu links in new tab

Tags: sharepoint-online

The menu bar on my new SharePoint page has a dropdown that points to a PDF document. Currently it is opening the PDF document in the same tab, how can I make this open in a new tab? The PDF is stored in the Site Contents of the site.

I have tried bit.ly, but it still opens in the same tab. I even just set it to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), but again, it opened in the same tab.

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, if you want to open the document in a new web, there is a sipmle method: just click the PDF with Ctrl hold, then you could open it in a new window.

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.